# UIPageControl with UITableView

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, uiscrollview, uipagecontrol

I want a page control(UIPageControl) on a view (UIViewController) with table view(UITable) on each page.
Is it possible? If YES then HOW?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create `UITableView` in `CellForRowAtIndexPath` and then create the `UIScrollView` which you can add to `UITableView` and attach your `UIPageControl` on `UIScrollView`.

Comment: I didn't understand, can you explain it better?

Comment: alrite. so can you explain me more how do you want it ? U need a tableview in uipagecontrol. I guess you dont need it if you have UIScrollView to work around that part.

Comment: Sure, maybe you can think of other soluction.I have 3 tables, like Favorites, History and Notifications. I have a UIView with others things (like buttons and searchBar) and in the bottom half of the UIView I have a UITableView. The UITableView shows the table of Favorites. I want with swipes to change between tables. I thought about UIPageControl and UIScrollView but maybe there is other alternatives...

Comment: Alrite. So have you created UITableView Favorites rite. So now add UIScrollView of the width and height of the tableView and attach UIPageControl to it. In code: scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, frame.size.width, frame.size.height)]; [[cell contentView] addSubView: scrollview]; pageControl = [[UIPageControl alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 50, frame.size.width, frame.size.height)];
[pageControl setNumberOfPages:4];
[[cell contentView] addSubview:pageControl];Ignore my coding since not tried on xcode.