# adding a page control to UITableView

Tags: uitableview, xamarin.ios, uipagecontrol

I have a UITableView that we're looking to adjust to have a carousel-like effect to items in our table that the user has pinned to the top.

[image: example]

I see that the page control is a view controller and the other item is just the dot container. I've seen a few other SO answers suggest I use a UIScrollview with the page control but in all those cases their data was just images and in my case it's a combination of text, buttons, and images so I'm lost on what a good clean solution would be.

Comment: a picture illustrating what you're trying to accomplish would help a lot

Comment: Normally the scrolling orientation of `UITableView` is vertical but `UIPageControl` is horizontal so we often use `page control` on  ScrollView rather than TableView  , for  complex UI you can customize a `View` which contains those elements and add them one by one on ScrollView, it is not difficulty .

Comment: I updated to have a visual of what we want to do

Comment: @ColeX-MSFT the issue with doing a view is these cells are complex and contains things like a collectionview (for an image gallery), animated gifs, buttons, etc. it's a very complex UI and iOS isn't making it easy like android has.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comment , we can't just combine `TabView + PageControl`, `ScrollView` is also needed in this scenario .

1. Create a `ScrollView` to wrap all the views/elements ,and put the ScrollView  into `Cell.ContentView`.
2. Add `PageControl` into `Cell.ContentView`.

Refer to

[UIScrollView and UIPageControl within UITableView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5092212/uiscrollview-and-uipagecontrol-within-uitableview)

[UIPageControl with UITableView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8523353/uipagecontrol-with-uitableview)

#### Update

Is the following screen shot you want ?

[image]

#### Sample code

```
 public class User
    {
        public string icon { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string content { get; set; }
        public string image { get; set; }

    }

    [Register("UIViewController1")]
    public class UIViewController1 : UIViewController
    {
        public UIViewController1()
        {
        }

        public override void ViewDidLoad()
        {
            base.ViewDidLoad();

            UITableView table = new UITableView(View.Bounds); // defaults to Plain style
            List<User> tableItems = new List<User>();
            tableItems.Add(new User { icon = "dog.png", name = "Cole", content = "I'm test1", image = "bg1.PNG" });
            tableItems.Add(new User { icon = "dog.png", name = "Kevin", content = "I'm test222222222", image = "bg2.PNG" });
            tableItems.Add(new User { icon = "dog.png", name = "Tom", content = "I'm test333333_33333333", image = "bg3.PNG" });

            table.Source = new TableSource(tableItems);
            Add(table);


        }

    }

    public class TableSource : UITableViewSource
    {

        List<User> TableItems;
        string CellIdentifier = "TableCell";

        public TableSource(List<User> items)
        {
            TableItems = items;
        }

        public override nint RowsInSection(UITableView tableview, nint section)
        {
            return TableItems.Count;
        }

        int CellHeight = 250;

        public override nfloat GetHeightForRow(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
        {
            return CellHeight;
        }

        public override UITableViewCell GetCell(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
        {
            UITableViewCell cell = tableView.DequeueReusableCell(CellIdentifier);
            User item = TableItems[indexPath.Row];

            //if there are no cells to reuse, create a new one
            if (cell == null)
            {
                cell = new UITableViewCell(UITableViewCellStyle.Default, CellIdentifier);

                UIScrollView sc = new UIScrollView();
                sc.Frame = new CGRect(0, 0, UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Width, CellHeight-10);

                for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                {
                    UIImageView image = new UIImageView();
                    image.Frame = new CGRect(i* UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Width + 20, 10, 50, 50);
                    image.Layer.MasksToBounds = true;
                    image.Layer.CornerRadius = 25;
                    image.Image = UIImage.FromFile(item.icon);
                    sc.Add(image);

                    UILabel label = new UILabel();
                    label.Frame = new CGRect(i * UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Width+80, 10, 100, 50);
                    label.TextColor = UIColor.LightGray;
                    label.Text = item.name;
                    sc.Add(label);


                    UILabel label2 = new UILabel();
                    label2.Frame = new CGRect(i * UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Width +20, 60, 300, 60);
                    label2.Text = item.content;
                    sc.Add(label2);

                    UIImageView image2 = new UIImageView();
                    image2.Frame = new CGRect(i * UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Width + 100, 130, 150, 100);
                    image2.Image = UIImage.FromFile(item.image);
                    sc.Add(image2);
                }

                sc.ContentSize = new CGSize(10 * UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Width, CellHeight-10);
                sc.PagingEnabled = true;
                sc.ShowsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false;

                UIPageControl page = new UIPageControl();
                page.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Red;
                page.Frame = new CGRect(0, CellHeight-10, cell.ContentView.Frame.Width, 10);
                page.Pages = 10;
                page.CurrentPage = 0;

                cell.ContentView.Add(sc);
                cell.ContentView.Add(page);


                sc.Scrolled += (object sender, EventArgs e) => {
                    var pageWidth = sc.Frame.Size.Width;
                    var fractionalPage = sc.ContentOffset.X / pageWidth;
                    var p = Math.Floor(fractionalPage);
                    page.CurrentPage = (int)p;
                };
            }

            return cell;
        }
    }
```

Comment: my main issue is it's not just 1 thing going in there(like every example out there is doing) but many things, think of it like a Facebook post that can scroll horizontally, how do I achieve that? iOS doesn't have fragments like Android

Comment: Yes that's we exactly what I want

Comment: I attach the sample code you can refer to it .